# How to design live tiles in android like Windows phones?

Tags: android

Is there any way we can design a live tiles in android like windows phone?  If so can you please guide me

Comment: follow this one design your own layout  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16466914/how-to-create-layout-with-6-buttons-like-windows-tiles

Comment: I wanted to know whether we can able to design a live titles?

Comment: This question is too generic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hello you have to look at android design principles ,
just look at this [link](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/pure-android.html)

Comment: well am impressed with the live tiles as it lets users make the best out of their start screens. User can pin all of their installed apps in order to view the latest updates without opening them.I just thought that to implement on my android project. Anyway thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use fragments for mimicking live tiles in android!
The container for the fragments should be dynamically created frame layout or any other layout.
You can add a long click listener for these layouts, to show options like unpin,re-size as in windows.
Add a drag listener too, so that the user can freely drag and drop the view any where within the parent layout.
I hope this idea is pretty clear.