# RecyclerView with CardView as Dashboard or like a Windows Tiles

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview, dashboard

I spent many time looking for the solution How to do the Windows tiles liked interface, also knowing as Dashboard. I want use for it RecyclerView with CardView. I found old solution but there used LinearLayout with Buttons: [How to create layout with 6 buttons like windows tiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16466914/how-to-create-layout-with-6-buttons-like-windows-tiles)

What I have at this moment:
[image]

What I want:
[image]

I have six CardViews, they should occupy the entire area of the parent RelativeLayout and be the same size regardless of the width of the screen.

In portrait mode I have 2 columns and in landscape - 3 cols.

```
 recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        int columns = resources.getConfiguration()
                .orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE ? 3 : 2;

        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), columns);
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new GridSpacingItemDecoration(columns,
                Utils.dpToPx(resources, 3), true));
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As always, after I write here a question, after a while the solution comes by itself. Here's how I solved this

**In your RecyclerView Adapter:**

```
@Override
public HomeTilesAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.home_tile_item, parent, false);
    int h = parent.getHeight();
    // margin - activity_vertical_margin
    // rows - number of rows in diffrent display modes
    h = (h - Math.round(margin*2))/rows;

    RecyclerView.LayoutParams params = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) itemView.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = h;
    itemView.setLayoutParams(params);

    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}
```

This decision solves the problem, but in the process I faced another problem. On the tablets the icon looks very small, it looks not beautiful. How I solved this issue you can read this post: [ImageView size for phones and tablets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44803011/imageview-size-for-phones-and-tablets/44806605)

**Result**

[image]

Comment: I don't understand how to take margin